# How to write $|a+b|-|b| $ without absolute value: Is this correct?

Tags: calculus

This is an exercise in Spivak. I tried to write $|a+b|-|b|$ without absolute value signs.

> Please could someone tell me if this is correct?

Here is what I did:

I distinguish cases based on whether $a+b$ and $b$ are positive or negative.

Case 1: If $a+b, b \ge 0$ then $|a+b|-|b| = a$.

Case 2: If $a+b \ge 0$ and $b<0$ then $|a+b|-|b| = a+b+b = a + 2b$.

Case 3: If $a+b<0$ and $b\ge 0$ then $|a+b|-|b| = -a -2b$.

Case 4: If $a+b,b < 0$ then $|a+b|-|b| = -a$.

I checked with some actual numbers and it agreed with the results.

> Is this the way to do it? Or is there a way without case distinction?

Comment: This is the way to go. You are right.

Comment: Yes, it is correct.